# Dynamically generate list of Sequelize "Or" clauses

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have the following Sequelize findAll query, where I intend to perform a "like" match on the title column for ANY of the words within the "queryTerms" array.  The contents and size of the queryTerms array may change.  How can I dynamically supply the findAll function with this list?

````
let queryTerms = ["pen", "pencil", "marker"];

  Page.findAll({
    where: {
      title: {
        [Op.or]: {
          [Op.like]: queryTerms[0],
...
          [Op.like]: queryTerms[n]
        }
      },
      status:0
    }
}); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Op.regexp to address the challenge:

```
let queryTerms = ["pen", "pencil", "marker"];
let queryTerm = queryTerms.join("|");

  Page.findAll({
    where: {
      title: {
        [Op.regexp]: `${queryTerm}`
      },
      status:0
    }
});
```